# what's wrong with my simple calculator, it doesn't error and doesn't execute

Tags: python

I can't quite figure out why my code won't work.

Whenever I click run, it doesn't follow back with a traceback error, it just says process finished with exit code 0.

I thought it might be the casefold but then when I applied it to `"Y"`. casefold it wouldn't work full stop.

```
def calculate():

    operator = input("please select the kind of maths you would like to do")
    if operator == "+":

        num1 = int(input('Enter first number: '))
        num2 = int(input('Enter second number: '))
        print('{} + {} ='.format(num1, num2))
        print(num1 + num2)

    elif operator == "-":

        num1 = int(input("enter first number: "))
        num2 = int(input("enter second number: "))
        print("{} - {} =".format(num1, num2))
        print(num1 - num2)

    elif operator == "*":

        num1 = int(input("enter first number: "))
        num2 = int(input("enter second number: "))
        print("{} * {} =".format(num1, num2))
        print(num1 * num2)

    elif operator == "/":

        num1 = int(input("enter first number: "))
        num2 = int(input("enter second number: "))
        print("{} / {} =".format(num1, num2))
        print(num1 / num2)

    else:
        _exit = input("would you like to exit? type Y for YES and N for NO")
        if _exit.casefold() == "y":
                sys.exit()
        else:
                calculate()
```

Comment: Did you call the function?

Comment: How do you call `calculate`?

Comment: add a line at the bottom with no indentation. calculate()

Comment: Remove the last `else` statement and add `calculate()` without any indendation at the bottom.

Comment: thanks guys this solved my problem. I thought it would still work because I was calling the function at the end, but it has to be done outside the function then ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `calculate()` at the very end to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this `calculate()` function first (at least it's not being executed in your code sample).

```
def calculate()
    # func code here

#Exec this function
calculate()
```

I guess it should be like this:

```
def calculate():

    operator = input("please select the kind of maths you would like to do")
    if operator == "+":

        num1 = int(input('Enter first number: '))
        num2 = int(input('Enter second number: '))
        print('{} + {} ='.format(num1, num2))
        print(num1 + num2)

    elif operator == "-":

        num1 = int(input("enter first number: "))
        num2 = int(input("enter second number: "))
        print("{} - {} =".format(num1, num2))
        print(num1 - num2)

    elif operator == "*":

        num1 = int(input("enter first number: "))
        num2 = int(input("enter second number: "))
        print("{} * {} =".format(num1, num2))
        print(num1 * num2)

    elif operator == "/":

        num1 = int(input("enter first number: "))
        num2 = int(input("enter second number: "))
        print("{} / {} =".format(num1, num2))
        print(num1 / num2)

    else:
        _exit = input("would you like to exit? type Y for YES and N for NO")
        if _exit.casefold() == "y":
            sys.exit()
        else:
            calculate()

calculate()
```

Comment: Not really, because the _exit case is moot then. He wanted to start over/recurse.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher good catch, fixed! But that doesn't change the fact that this function still needs to be called first.

Comment: Hence my comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Put function calling `calculate()` at the end without any indent. Your function isn't even getting called, thus giving no error.